# What does $R[[X]]$ and $R(X)$ stands for?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, definition

I'm reviewing Linear Algebra these days and I saw these two notations in my notes without definition.

Those are, $R[[X]]$ and $R(X)$ where $R$ is a commutative ring with unity.

I remember that one of these denote the field of polynomials, but I don't know which one does..

Moreover, is there any notation for the set of polynomial functions?

Hoffman&Kunze's text denote it as $R[X]^{\sim}$ btw.

Comment: Usually, $R[[x]]$ is the power series ring, and $R(x)$ is the field of rational functions.

Comment: The set of polynomial *functions* is trickier than you think. You probably just mean "polynomials."

Comment: @rschwieb What do you mean by "polynomial functions" then?

Comment: Over certain rings, if you interpret their polynomials as functions, two different polynomials can produce the same function. In algebra we simply don't have much necessity for interpreting them as functions, and we want all polynomials to stand on their own.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes you are right. Even when $R$ is a field, if $R$ is not infinite, two different polynomials could produce the same function. Nevertheless, I don't get why "polynomial functions" is  trickier. For an example, there is a *non-injective but surjective* homomorphism between $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and the Mobius group $Aut(\hat{\mathbb{C}})$, and I think this gives (probably) all algebraic properties of $Aut(\hat{\mathbb{C}})$..

Comment: @linearalgebrareviewr I'm just saying that they're not as easy to describe as polynomials, and generally not as useful. Sets of functions are pretty useful, but I can't think of any place where the set of polynomial functions is particularly useful.  I don't see the connection of your example to the set of polynomial functions...regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically:

- $R[x]$ denotes the set of polynomials over $R$
- When $R$ is a domain, $R(x)$ denotes the set of rational polynomials over $R$
- $R[[x]]$ denotes the formal power series over $R$
- $R((x))$ denotes the Laurent series over $R$

---

vuur asked an interesting question in the comments which I can speak to here. The answer is "If $R$ is a commutative domain, then yes, $R(x)$ is the field of fractions for $R[x]$, and $R((x))$ is the field of fractions for $R[[x]]$. In that case, $R((x))$ can be expressed as "quotients of power series."

What's going on here is that $R(x)$ is almost always defined as quotients of polynomials, and that necessitates $R$ (and hence $R[x]$) to be at least a domain, so that the product of two denominators is nonzero. However, $R((x))$ is not usually defined via quotients, it's usually described as "power series, but you can have negative powers of $x$, and you can start at any power of $x$ and go upward." Thus $R((x))$ is defined for any ring $R$, but it is not necessarily quotients of things from $R[[x]]$.

Comment: Just to be sure, is [] related to [[]] as () is to (())?

Comment: @vuur Good comment: I adapted the solution to it.